# Is it possible to restart my plug-in in javascript?

Tags: javascript, xul

I am developping my firefox extension thanks to xul and javascript and I would like to know if someone can tell me how I can do to restart the plugin ? For example, by clicking in a button or something like that.

Regards.

Comment: Why do you need to restart the plugin?

Comment: It's necessary to take into account some changes. And it would be better to do it automatically, like when you install a plugin and Firefox asks you if you want to restart now.

Comment: @user2302725 - Maybe you should explain a little better what you are trying to accomplish, and why do you think you need a restart button.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that without creating a specific function to reset everything in your extension. One thing you can do is install an extension like [Restartless Restart](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-pt/firefox/addon/restartless-restart/) that creates a button and a shortcut to restart firefox very easily (and your Extension with it).